# Organic shape that fills up space with Paper.js

Tags: p5.js, paperjs

I'm aware my question is maybe somewhat lazy. But I hope someone could maybe give me head start with my idea, or can provide me with an existing code example that points me in the right direction.

[image]

I want to create an organic shape/blob that more or less fills up existing space, but wraps around typographical elements. Whenever these elements move around, the shape should adjust itself accordingly. I was looking at Paper.js where examples like http://paperjs.org/examples/candy-crash/ and http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/ make it seem like this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`path.subtract()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#subtract) boolean operation, along with the [`path.smooth()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#smooth) function to smooth your shape with the type of smoothing of your choice.

Here is a [demo sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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). You can also try to smooth the rectangles ; and maybe randomly add points on your curves or randomly displace all segment handles.